# properly formatting object to json with RABL

Tags: json, rabl

I have an array @user_designs which has a few attributes, including name, theme_id, and token. Currently my RABL looks like this:

```
collection @user_designs 
attributes :token, :name, :theme_id
```

and displays this:

```
[
    {
        "user_design": {"token":"U081247840","name":"My Design","theme_id":1}},
    {
        "user_design": {"token":"U783042565","name":"facebook images","theme_id":2}
    }
]
```

what id like to see from the json is something like this:

```
{
     "status" : true,
     "user_designs" : 
           {
                "U081247840": {"name":"My Design","theme_id":1},
                "U783042565": {"name":"facebook images","theme_id":2}
           }

}
```

I tried looking through the docs but i couldn't figure it out. The status is just a variable that i want to embed that's independent of the collection. I also want all of the user designs in a hash called "user designs" that is indexed by its token.

How would i do this in RABL? I am using rails 3.2

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this out, but it should work based on the docs:

```
collection @user_designs 
extends 'user_designs/show'
```

In 'user_designs/show'

```
object @user_design => @user_design.token
attributes :name, :theme_id
```

To index the objects in the collection by token, you should do it in your controller or define an order scope in the model.